# Unit test an Android activity

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing

I'm making an application in the android studio. And for this project, I have to make multiple unit tests. But I have no idea what I can unit test this application. I'm really struggling with unit testing so I would appreciate if someone could help me, or come up with some unit tests I can implement in my project. Its an app with a listview that retrieves data from a web service.

Code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] data;
String[] waarde;
String[] hoog;
String[] laag;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build());

    getData();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Showdata.class);
        intent.putExtra("teeltbed", listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void getData()
{
    String getData = null;
    String dbResult = "empty";
    dbConnect database = new dbConnect(this);

    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Lamp";
        getData = "?query=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        //data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
        String link = "http://10.247.240.53/kas/lampen.php";
        dbResult = database.execute(link).get();
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }

    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(dbResult);
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Lamp");
        waarde = new String[array.length()];
        data = new String[array.length()];
        hoog = new String[array.length()];
        laag = new String[array.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
        {
            jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
            data[i] = jsonObject.getString("teeltbed");
            waarde[i] = "A: " + jsonObject.getString("waarde") + " %";
            hoog[i] = "H: " + jsonObject.getString("hoog") + " W/m2";
            laag[i] = "L: " + jsonObject.getString("laag") + " W/m2";

        }

        listView.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(data, waarde, hoog, laag));
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String[] data, waarde;

    dataListAdapter(){
        data = null;
        waarde = null;
    }

    public dataListAdapter(String[] sdata, String[]swaarde, String[]shoog, String[]slaag)
    {
        data = sdata;
        waarde = swaarde;
        hoog = shoog;
        laag = slaag;

    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list, parent, false);
        TextView t1, t2, t3, t4;
        t1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        t2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item2);
        t3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item3);
        t4 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item4);
        t1.setText(data[position]);
        t2.setText(waarde[position]);
        t3.setText(hoog[position]);
        t4.setText(laag[position]);
        return (row);
    }
}

class Sproeier
{
 public int TeeltBed;
 public String Stand;
 public double Actueel;
 public double Hoog;
 public double Laag;

 public void Sproeier()
 {
     int teeltbed;
     double hoog;
     double laag;
 }
}

class Lamp {

}

public static class ScadaWebservice
{

}

class Kas
{

    public void kas()
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Often retrofitting unit tests on code already written leads to a 'I can't unit test this'. Code written with unit tests first are testable because they'll expose hooks to create a test on. For Android UI testing you might check out https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals

Comment: unit tests can be implmeneted only on pure java classes (it should not contain any thing related to android )  for that you need to adopt any design pattern as adnroid architecture components also suggests.. we have mvvm and mvp you can got to android blue prints on github and look at the examples of mvp and mvvm they have unit and espresso test cases as well

Answer (score 0):

So indeed your app doesn't many methods to test but from what I see you can test:

- the list view on item click listener
- if you divide the getData in smaller pieces you can test the if you get a response or error and if you get data in case of a response

For UI testing you might want to check this course chapter 8:
https://eu.udacity.com/course/advanced-android-app-development--ud855

or this codelab for more ideas:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0